# My DOM doesn't update, but the debug says the position is changing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a javascript clicker game, but currently there's a problem. The gems that appear after you click don't update, but according to the debug prints I put the position is changing. This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gem Blaster</title>
        <style>
            :root {
                --hitsleft: 5;
            }

            .gem {
                position: absolute;
                border-radius: 100%;
                width: calc(min(calc(var(--hitsleft)), 9) * 10%);
                height: calc(min(calc(var(--hitsleft)), 9) * 10%);
                border: 2px solid black;
                background-color: transparent;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .lowerbtn {
                position: absolute;
                border-radius: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border: 2px solid black;
                background-color: transparent;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .gamewindow {
                position: absolute;
                overflow: clip;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                background-color: transparent;
            }

            .gem span {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .gem span::selection {
                background: transparent;
            }

            #fallenGem {
                --fillcolor: rgb(31, 163, 229);
                position: absolute;
                fill: var(--fillcolor);
                z-index: 2;
                width: 10%;
                height: 10%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="gamewindow"> <!-- So the game is always fair even if your screen size is different -->
            <div class="gem"><button onclick="lowerit()" class="lowerbtn"></button><span id="hitsleft">5</span></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var hitsleft = 5;
            var hitpower = 1;
            var nexthl = 7;
            var r = document.querySelector(":root");

            function lowerit() {
                hitsleft -= hitpower;
                if (hitsleft <= 0) {
                    hitsleft = nexthl;
                    nexthl += Math.round(nexthl * 0.3);
                    console.log("Attempting to run particles()")
                    particles();
                    console.log("Got past particles")
                }
                r.style.setProperty("--hitsleft", hitsleft);
                document.getElementById("hitsleft").innerHTML = hitsleft;
            }

            function particles() {
                console.log("Particles ran!")
                arr = []
                arrvelx = []
                arrvely = []
                arrposx = []
                arrposy = []
                for (var i = 0; i<nexthl; i++) {
                    console.log("Creating Particle...")
                    svg = document.createElement("div")
                    Object.assign(svg, {id: "fallenGem", width: "256", height: "256", viewbox: "0 0 256 256"});
                    svg.innerHTML = "<svg id=\"fallenGem\" viewBox=\"0 0 256 256\"><polygon points=\"256,128 192,64, 64,64 0,128 128,256\"></polygon></svg>"
                    console.log(svg)
                    console.log("adding to body")
                    document.body.appendChild(svg)
                    arr.push(svg)
                    arrvelx.push((Math.random()+1)/2*100)
                    arrvely.push(0)
                    arrposx.push(0)
                    arrposy.push(0)
                }
                while (arr.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                        svg = arr[i]
                        velx = arrvelx[i]
                        vely = arrvely[i]
                        posx = arrposx[i]
                        posy = arrposy[i]

                        console.log("Particle updated!")
                        svg.style.left = `${posx}%`;
                        svg.style.top = `${-posy}%`;

                        velx *= 0.4;
                        vely *= 0.7;

                        vely += -4;

                        posx += velx;
                        posy += vely;

                        arr[i] = svg
                        arrvelx[i] = velx
                        arrvely[i] = vely
                        arrposx[i] = posx
                        arrposy[i] = posy

                        console.log(posy)

                        if (posy < -100) {
                            console.log("removing one!")
                            arr.splice(i,1)
                            arrvelx.splice(i,1)
                            arrvely.splice(i,1)
                            arrposx.splice(i,1)
                            arrposy.splice(i,1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I look at the console, it says there is no error, and it says that "posy" is lowering, even though the gems just stay in their same random position. I was expecting them to fall, but they just stayed there. I understand that I haven't implemented deleted the svg object, but I'll do that later. What I want right now is for the gems to fall down.

Comment: Animations won't work if you are trying to update elements within a while/for loop.  The display just won't change (as you noticed).  [Read about animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) - especially the "scheduled updates" part.

Comment: so you can't change the left style property without redrawing the SVG?

Comment: You can!  You just need to use an animation technique to see it moving.

Comment: okay, could you put it in an answer so I can have this question answered (without answering my own question, because I don't fully understand how to use an animation technique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split your particles function into a setup function and an animate function.  The animate function is called initially by the code but then keeps scheduling itself until there are no particles left.  [Read about requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

When we calculate the new speed and position of the particle, we are basing it on actual seconds elapsing (so all of the incremental changes are multiplied by dt) - you will probably have to adjust your initial speed values.

```js
let arr = [];
let arrvelx = [];
let arrvely = [];
let arrposx = [];
let arrposy = [];

function setup() {
  for (var i = 0; i<nexthl; i++) {
      console.log("Creating Particle...")
      svg = document.createElement("div")
      Object.assign(svg, {id: "fallenGem", width: "256", height: "256", viewbox: "0 0 256 256"});
      svg.innerHTML = "<svg id=\"fallenGem\" viewBox=\"0 0 256 256\"><polygon points=\"256,128 192,64, 64,64 0,128 128,256\"></polygon></svg>"
      console.log(svg)
      console.log("adding to body")
      document.body.appendChild(svg)
      arr.push(svg)
      arrvelx.push((Math.random()+1)/2*100)
      arrvely.push(0)
      arrposx.push(0)
      arrposy.push(0)
  }  
}

function animateParticles(time) {
  let dt = time / 1000; // dt is time in seconds since last animation frame
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      svg = arr[i]
      velx = arrvelx[i]
      vely = arrvely[i]
      posx = arrposx[i]
      posy = arrposy[i]

      console.log("Particle updated!")
      svg.style.left = `${posx}%`;
      svg.style.top = `${-posy}%`;

      velx *= 0.4 * dt;
      vely *= 0.7 * dt;

      vely += -4 * dt;

      posx += velx * dt;
      posy += vely * dt;

      arr[i] = svg
      arrvelx[i] = velx
      arrvely[i] = vely
      arrposx[i] = posx
      arrposy[i] = posy

      console.log(posy)

      if (posy < -100) {
          console.log("removing one!")
          arr.splice(i,1)
          arrvelx.splice(i,1)
          arrvely.splice(i,1)
          arrposx.splice(i,1)
          arrposy.splice(i,1)
      }
   }
   
   if (arr.length > 0) {
     // keep animating if there are still particles
     window.requestAnimationFrame(animateParticles);
   }

}

setup();
window.requestAnimationFrame(animateParticles);
```

Comment: How would I get delta time? Current dt is 0, which means nothing happens every frame.

Comment: When the function is called by requestAnimationFrame, `time` will not be zero, it will be passed in a timestamp, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame.  I modified the code a little since we can just call it initially using requestAnimationFrame and not need to have a default value for time.

Comment: yes, the documentation says that, but the gems are just hanging in the air not moving.

Comment: Also, just deleting dt allows the gems to move (and I just used that and continued programming the game)

Comment: Did you change the speed values like I suggested?

Comment: yes, the velx is now multiplied by 0.8, vely multiplied by 0.9, and vely subtracted by 1.8. This creates gems that go up high when clicked, and go down at a medium speed.